# Consuming JSON in a WCF Service without using a DataContract, but still use the application/json Content-Type

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, content-type

From my understanding of WCF Services, when you use the application/json Content-Type, you then have to use a DataContract approach, such as:

```
[DataContract]
public class Thingy
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IThingy
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "thingy", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Thingy CreateThingy(Thingy thingy);
}
```

Is there a way to still be able to use the application/json Content-Type, but have the prototype be something like:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "thingy", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Stream CreateThingy(Stream thingy);
```

The Web.Config file entries are:

```
<service name="ThingySvc.SMSSystem">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ThingySvc.ThingySvcBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ThingySvc.IThingy" />
</service>

<behavior name="ThingySvc.ThingySvcBehavior">
    <webHttp />
</behavior>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming WCF REST Service with multiple parameters WITHOUT DataContract](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9635006/10263)

Comment: My question is not a duplicate that I can tell.  I want to send a JSON string to the WCF Service, plain and simple, but use the Content-Type "application/json" .  I can do this if I set the Content-Type to "application/x-www-form-encoded" and pass a Stream parameter.  Essentially, what I want to do is to pass the JSON in the request body, and use Content-Type "application/json".

Comment: Could you please explain, why do you want to use this signature? `Stream CreateThingy(Stream thingy)` Looks like you want to have only on one `OperationContract` in your `ServiceContract`